# Java Thread random output

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

```
public class Rough {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TestThread1 testThread1 = new TestThread1();
        TestThread2 testThread2 = new TestThread2();
        testThread1.start();
        testThread2.start();
        // testThread1.stop();
        System.out.println(testThread1.getName());
        System.out.println(testThread2.getName());
    }

}

class TestThread1 extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        System.out
                .println("MyThread1 running :: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}

class TestThread2 extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        System.out
                .println("MyThread2 running :: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

Its giving random output each time i execute it.

```
Thread-0
Thread-1
MyThread1 running :: 1398752090142
MyThread2 running :: 1398752090142
```

next time

```
MyThread1 running :: 1398752090142
Thread-0
Thread-1
MyThread2 running :: 1398752090142
```

next time

```
Thread-0
MyThread1 running :: 1398752090142
Thread-1
MyThread2 running :: 1398752090142
```

Could anyone please explain why is it happening so?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your problem ?

Comment: @MrROY, i think he does not understand why the outputs are different.

Comment: 3 threads doing `System.out` simultaneously. What do you expect?

Comment: I was expecting each thread to behave same each time they are executed. Each thread was supposed to take same time of execution and printing using syso. Its clear after running it in debug mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It depends solely on the JVM Thread scheduler to schedule a thread. It may do it in any order when you have multiple threads. Hence you see different output.

Answer (score 1):

When you start a thread, the started thread runs in parallel of all the already running threads. The thread scheduler dispatches the various threads on the available processors, and each thread gets some processor time, each in its turn. But the processor, the order and the time assigned to each thread is up to the OS thread scheduler, and you have absolutely no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty expected behavior for multiple threads like this. The reason is that when you have multiple threads you can make no assumptions about the order or speed at which they run, no matter if you're running them on a multicore/threaded processor or not.

In the case that you're on a processor that only supports a single thread at a time, the order/time that threads will run is dependent entirely on how the JVM schedules your threads. Because it can schedule the threads however it wants and for as long as it wants you'll have some threads reaching their print calls earlier than others.

In the case that you're on a process that allows concurrent running of threads, you'll essentially get a race condition between various threads as to which one reaches the print statement first.